# Handler not implementing a delay, instead it crashes the application

Tags: java, android

I am facing an issue while implementing delay with handlers.

In the code below I have two handlers. The first one works fine within the `isGameOver()` method. However, within the `resetBoard` method it is not working and what it seems to do is loop within `resetBoard`.

How can this be fixed?

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mima.tictactoe, PID: 10915
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
                      at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:163)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.player2Wins(MainActivityPlayer1.java:340)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.isGameOver(MainActivityPlayer1.java:129)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:283)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.player2Wins(MainActivityPlayer1.java:340)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.isGameOver(MainActivityPlayer1.java:129)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:283)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.player2Wins(MainActivityPlayer1.java:340)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.isGameOver(MainActivityPlayer1.java:129)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:283)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.player2Wins(MainActivityPlayer1.java:340)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.isGameOver(MainActivityPlayer1.java:129)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:283)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.access$200(MainActivityPlayer1.java:20)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1$3.run(MainActivityPlayer1.java:140)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Code:

```
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    return;
                }

                turnsCount++;

                if (playerOneMove) {
                    ((Button) v).setText("X");
                    ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);
                    isGameOver();
                }

            }

            public void isGameOver() {

                if (checkGameIsWon()) {
                    if (playerOneMove) {
                        player1Wins();
                    } else {
                        player2Wins();
                    }
                } else if (turnsCount == 9) {
                    draw();
                } else {
                    playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
                    if (!playerOneMove) {
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                computerMove();
                            }
                        }, random.nextInt(2000 - 1000 + 1000) + 1000);
                    }
                }
            }

  private void computerMove() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];
        List<Button> emptyButtons = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                if (field[i][j].equals("")) {
                    emptyButtons.add(buttons[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }

selectButton = emptyButtons.get(random.nextInt(emptyButtons.size()));

selectButton.setText("O");
                selectButton.setTextColor(playerO);
                firstComputerMove = false;
                turnsCount++;
                isGameOver();

        }

            private void player1Wins() {
                playerOnePoints++;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updatePointsText();
                resetBoard();
            }

            private void resetBoard() {

                final Handler handlerReset = new Handler();
                handlerReset.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                                buttons[i][j].setText("");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    },2000);
        } 

    private boolean checkGameIsWon() {
            String[][] field = new String[3][3];

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                        && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                        && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                        && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                        && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                    && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                    && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }

            if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                    && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                    && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void player1Wins() {
            playerOnePoints++;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updatePointsText();
            resetBoard();
        }

        private void player2Wins() {
            playerTwoPoints++;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Computer wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updatePointsText();
            resetBoard();
            firstComputerMove = true;
            computerMove();
        }

        private void draw() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            resetBoard();
            playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
            switchPlayerTurn();
            if (!playerOneMove){
                firstComputerMove = true;
                computerMove();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Paste your logcat showing error here.

Comment: Will do, give me 5 mins

Comment: Error included in question

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error of the stack trace, your error is in your `Random.nextInt()` in your `computerMove()` method.

The documentation stated parameter of `Random.nextInt (int bound)` must be positive. But in your stack trace, it says you pass 0 as parameter.

**Why that happens**

When you use `Handler.postDelayed`, you tell them wait for 2000ms then execute the code in the background, and therefore when `computerMove()` is executed, the board is not yet finished being reset. And that's why computer legal move is 0, and you pass that as parameter. Error!

**Solution**

I dont recommend you to use `Handler`, but if you want to use it, you can use callback after the process is finished. It makes sure that `computerMove()` will be executed AFTER `resetBoard()` completely finished.

**Suggestion**

There are many ways to solve this. What I'm going to share with you is just basic one, maybe others have better idea, or maybe you will have better idea as well after reading this.

Principle in Android App is that your app must be responsive. It means there shouldn't be long processes that will make your app goes ANR. Therefore,we have AsyncTask, Handler, WorkManager, Thread pools, etc. And when we start those job, be responsive by telling User that we're processing something.

So if you have any logical process, always do in the background. I suggest, `AsyncTask` for starter, very easy to implement and it does have `onPostExecute` that wil run on UI Thread after the process is done. [Read more on AsyncTask.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

But to be honest, your codes in `resetBoard()` are all UI related, so try to do it without Handler. Is it still good? It should be, as it only changes 9 buttons text.

On the other hand, `computerMove()` is a good way to use AsyncTask. As in the future you might want to do some complex calculation or computation to the next move and it might take times, so pls do it in the background.

Comment: Thank you very much, can I just see an example on how you will implement the callback just to make sure I implement it correctly?

Comment: I don't mind implementing an alternative way to implement a delay if you think there's a better way?

Comment: Ok. I just added some suggestions, you might want to try. :)